# How to work with icons assets on Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm developing my first real flutter project and I have a question about assets. Can I use platform assets to load my app icons? If no, I need create flutter assets to my app. But, what is recommended size to general icons?

Flutter doc say:

*Main assets are presumed to match a nominal pixel ratio of 1.0. To specify assets targeting different pixel ratios, place the variant assets in the application bundle under subdirectories named in the form "Nx", where N is the nominal device pixel ratio for that asset.*

But Android and IOS have many screen sizes. Using platform assets I create all icons according platform specification. So how I do in flutter? What are the specifications of general purpose icons?

Thanks!

Comment: you can probably use image icon class

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ImageIcon-class.html

to add assets, you need to add it to your pubspec.ymal

https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/

Comment: yes I know! but, what is recommended sizes?

Comment: I am really do not know about recommended screen sizes.

if you want to take a look at the closed issue report

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1208

here is the link

Answer (score 2):

If these are simple icons, then using an icon font, in the same manner as the built in [IconData](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/IconData-class.html), should obviate any concerns about scaling, since they are vector-based.

If you have (or can convert) your icon assets as SVG, then you can easily build Flutter icon fonts using http://fluttericon.com.  This will generate a TTF font and Dart code for your custom icons.